# How to apply datatable ellipsis to this column?

Tags: datatables

Here is my configuration for a column:

```
{
    data: 'matter',
    'render': function(data) {
    return data.mCust;
},
```

but I have no idea how I should apply the ellipsis function to it.

```
data: 'matter',
            'render': function(data) {
            data = data.mCust;
                return $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(5);
            }
        },
```

but that does not work. anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: [Shouldn't](https://datatables.net/blog/2016-02-26#Reusable-renderers) that be simply `{data: 'matter', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis(5)}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: $.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis